# Capybara login test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I want to test if login of a page works, so I create two tests if url change and if content change.

This is my view:

```
<%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true, placeholder: "Email" %>
<%= f.password_field :password, placeholder: "Password" %>
<%= f.submit "Login" %>
```

algorithm:

```
visit '/users/sign_in'
fill_in 'Email', with: email
fill_in 'Password', with: password
click_on 'Login'
```

Tests:

```
 expect(page).to have_content('Welcome')
```

Result : expected to find text "Welcome" in "Login"

```
expect(current_path).to eql('/home')
```

Result: expected: "/home" got: "/"

All the tests fails and I don't know why, I use valid logins and I can manually use the login with success.

Comment: Because your auth system redirects to `root_path` (/) and not `/home`.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root

Comment: also you should add the errors reported by running the tests. something like `expected current_path to eql('/home') but was '/'`

Comment: Add your authentication controller code if you need more help than the previous comments have provided. As a side note - using `expect(current_path).to eql('/home')` is bad practice in newer versions of capybara - instead use   `expect(page).to have_current_path('/home')`  -- it'll save you a lot of flaky errors when you move to a JS capable driver

Comment: expected "/?user[email]=email%40gmail.com&user[password]=123456&user[remember_me]=0&commit=login" to equal "/home"
Why the test is redirected to this url ?

Answer (score 0):

"expected to find text "Welcome" in "Login"", these errors generally occours when the page doesn't loads well but the test gets executed. So you should apply waits in your test. The following code should work for you:

```
visit '/users/sign_in'
page.should have_content("Wait for some text which is diaplayed on the page") //waits for the sign in page to load
fill_in 'Email', with: email
fill_in 'Password', with: password
click_on 'Login'
page.should have_no_content("Wait for the text which is available in the sign in page but not on next page") //waits for the sign in page to disappear and open welcome page.
page.should have_content("Welcome")
```

**Note:** Instead of waiting for some text you can also wait for css selectors

Hope this helps :)

Comment: nothing :/      Failure/Error: page.should have_no_content("Please")
       expected #has_no_content?("Please") to return true, got false

Comment: You can try increasing timeout for this waiting for an element to show, by increasing capybara default wait time before this line and reset it to DEFAULTWAITIME, after this step is done. You can also add screenshot for debugging this issue.